# How to add GeoJSON(MultiLineString) layer to a Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I need to create maps that will use GeoJSON data(MultiLineString format) as a data layer over a Google Map. I have created a Google Maps JavaScript API project, and have an API key.

I have tried the following examples:

**Example I:**
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-simple
(This renders a polygon but does not seem to support the styling of a MultiLineString).

**Example II:**
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-dragndrop
(This example allows for addition of GeoJSON via Drag and Drop but I do not see how to save the map and data layer.)

Sample GeoJSON MultiLineString from http://geojsonlint.com :

```
{
    "type": "MultiLineString",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [
                -105.0214433670044,
                39.57805759162015
            ],
            [
                -105.02150774002075,
                39.57780951131517
            ],
            [
                -105.02157211303711,
                39.57749527498758
            ],
            [
                -105.02157211303711,
                39.57716449836683
            ],
            [
                -105.02157211303711,
                39.57703218727656
            ],
            [
                -105.02152919769287,
                39.57678410330158
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                -105.01989841461182,
                39.574997872470774
            ],
            [
                -105.01959800720215,
                39.57489863607502
            ],
            [
                -105.01906156539916,
                39.57478286010041
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                -105.01717329025269,
                39.5744024519653
            ],
            [
                -105.01698017120361,
                39.574385912433804
            ],
            [
                -105.0166368484497,
                39.574385912433804
            ],
            [
                -105.01650810241699,
                39.5744024519653
            ],
            [
                -105.0159502029419,
                39.574270135602866
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                -105.0142765045166,
                39.57397242286402
            ],
            [
                -105.01412630081175,
                39.57403858136094
            ],
            [
                -105.0138258934021,
                39.57417089816531
            ],
            [
                -105.01331090927124,
                39.57445207053608
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your example data is not a `MultiLineString`, it is just a `LineString`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the [example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data)

> **Data class**
>
> **google.maps.Data class**
>
> A layer for displaying geospatial data. Points, line-strings and polygons can be displayed.
>
> Every Map has a Data object by default, so most of the time there is no need to construct one. For example:

```
var myMap = new google.maps.Map(...);
myMap.data.addGeoJson(...);
myMap.data.setStyle(...);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/d4hx7dyf/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, 70.1419),
      zoom: 3,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  map.data.addGeoJson(jsonData);
  map.data.setStyle({
    strokeColor: "blue"
  })

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
var jsonData = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "stroke": "#555555",
      "stroke-width": 2,
      "stroke-opacity": 1
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          79.8046875,
          45.583289756006316
        ],
        [
          73.828125,
          48.922499263758255
        ],
        [
          72.421875,
          46.07323062540838
        ],
        [
          72.0703125,
          42.553080288955826
        ],
        [
          79.453125,
          41.77131167976407
        ],
        [
          78.046875,
          37.71859032558816
        ],
        [
          72.7734375,
          34.016241889667015
        ],
        [
          66.796875,
          39.63953756436671
        ],
        [
          66.4453125,
          48.45835188280866
        ],
        [
          74.1796875,
          53.74871079689897
        ],
        [
          55.1953125,
          55.7765730186677
        ],
        [
          49.92187499999999,
          48.69096039092549
        ],
        [
          50.625,
          40.17887331434696
        ]
      ]
    }
  }]
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: map.data.addGeoJson(jsonData); did the trick for me. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You can add the GeoJSON like

```
function loadGeoJsonString(geoString) {
  var geojson = JSON.parse(geoString);
  map.data.addGeoJson(geojson);
}
```

With

```
map.data.setStyle({
  //Put styling here
});
```

you can style your added GeoJSON. So the styling is not applied when you load the GeoJSON but you can add it afterwards.