# How to catch exceptions when loading geoJSON into data layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am loading a feature collection into the map via maps.data.loadGeoJson().  Unfortunately, my data source occasionally returns a malformed GeoJson object (features is null, rather than an empty array) throwing an InvalidValueError.

An example of that data:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":null}
```

I'd like to be able to catch this error, but because loadGeoJson() is an asynchronous call, by the time the exception is thrown I have already exited the try block.   I have read ([Is it possible to catch exceptions thrown in a JavaScript async callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677783/is-it-possible-to-catch-exceptions-thrown-in-a-javascript-async-callback)) that the way to handle this is by placing the try/catch block in the callback.

Sounds pretty reasonable but I'm not sure what I should be setting as a condition in the try block.

```
map.data.loadGeoJson(url ,null,
    function(data){
        try(what_exactly){

        }catch(e){ }
    }
);
```

Is this the right approach, or am I on the wrong boat?  If I'm on the wrong boat, which is the right one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using [`loadGeoJson`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data), use [`addGeoJson`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data).

> - loadGeoJson
>
>   - Loads GeoJSON from a URL, and adds the features to the collection.
>   - Return Value: None
> - addGeoJson
>
>   - Adds GeoJSON features to the collection. Give this method a parsed JSON. The imported features are returned. **Throws an exception if the GeoJSON could not be imported**.
>   - Return Value: Array<[Data.Feature](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data.Feature)>

Here is a related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38491641/5995040) that provides a code implementation about `addGeoJson`.

Hope this helps!